# Minimizing costs to make a cylinder

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A cylinder must have a volume $V=4000$ and its made from just one rectangle sheet, so its top and bottom must be cut from this sheet.

I have to find the dimensions of this sheet such that the parts I lost (when I cutoff the top and the bottom) are the lowest.

I thought about minimize the difference between the area of the original sheet and the parts I'll use to make my cylinder:
[image]

(I imagine this is the best way to don't waste sheet - the original problem doesn't have any image).

So the area of the original sheet is
$$(h+2R)\cdot4R=4hR+8R^2$$
and the area I'll use to make the cylinder is
$$4hR+2\cdot\pi R^2$$
so the difference between them is
$$8R^2-2\pi R^2=0$$
and derivating it:
$$16R-4\pi R$$
which the only root is $R=0$. What is wrong?

Comment: Makes sense!  The thinner the cylinder, the less paper thrown away!  Of course, $h$ will get way too large!  You'll need a long sheet of paper!

Comment: Yes, it makes sense but it's not the way it should be. I mean, I should find a value of $R$ and $h$.

Comment: Math Lover has pointed out that I did not read carefully enough.  You did the right thing the first time because it asked to minimize the area cut away, not to minimize the area of the starting sheet.

Comment: Are you allowed to overfold the rectangle, so that it's made of more stacked layers? What I mean is, aren't you restricted to $h = 2πR$? (Assuming you fold the rectangle horizontally from your picture)

Comment: @StefanOctavian I don't believe so...  I think the problem is really this: given a sheet, minimize the loss you have when cutoff the top, the bottom and the side area to build a cylinder.

Comment: You should not forget that rectangle and circle are related.

To build the cylinder, the rectangle which will be the lateral face must have the base equal to the circumference of the circles, like the picture here https://imgur.com/RySayH7

Comment: @Raffaele I tried this way, and still I get $R=0$.

Comment: @mvfs314 can we use calculus or have you not learned that yet?

Comment: oops sorry didnt see that you had a calculus tag

Comment: @mvfs314 In my answer I mentioned that this problem is the same even if no rectangular or other sheet is brought into picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an equality constrained optimization problem, i.e.

\begin{equation}
\text{minimize} \quad 4hR + 8R^2 \quad \text{subject to} \quad \pi R^2 h = 4000, 
\end{equation}

which in turn can be turned in to

\begin{equation}
\text{minimize} \quad f(R) = 4 \frac{4000}{\pi R^2} R + 8R^2 =  \frac{16000}{\pi R} + 8R^2 . 
\end{equation}

This problem can be solved by setting $f'(R) = 0$ and solve for $R$, which yields $R^* = \left(\frac{1000}{\pi}\right)^{1/3}$. You can verify that it is indeed a minimum with $f''(R^*) > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that you are free to use any or all the sheets stocked in hardware supply store whose total area is $S$.

From the wasted area  we have the useful area.

$$ A_{usable} = S-A_{wasted}= A $$

$$ V= \pi R^2 h, A= 2 \pi R h + 2 \pi R^2 $$

Eliminate one variable, of relation derivate and find its value. Using other relation find the second variable ( details not included... for the usual exercise).

We end end up with result of relative proportion

$$ h=2 R$$

$$ V= 4000 = \pi R^2 \cdot 2 R\to R_{opt}=\left(\frac{2000}{\pi}\right)^\frac13, h_{opt}=R_{opt}/2$$

Point is, there is no need to *a priori* optimize the area that is anyway later on going to enter into mathematical optimization. The remainder area is negative. Multiplying  by $-1,$ the minimization and optimal solution cannot be affected, the constants play no role here.

From Variational calculus we can see the irrelevance of sign,

$$ \frac{\partial V_{R}}{\partial V_{h}}=\frac{\partial A_{R}}{\partial A_{h}}=\quad \frac{\partial A_{uR}}{\partial A_{uh}}=\frac{\partial A_{wR}}{\partial A_{wh}}.$$

Comment: Yes. But I imagined that the way I drew wouldn't waste too much sheet.

Comment: There is no need to do that, given that you are tackling the problem anyways.